# Styling chrome extension buttons

Tags: html, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

[image]

I am working on push notifications with two action buttons : **Know more** and **close** .By default these buttons on defining show vertically in the notification.How do I style them so that they appear inline horizontally .?

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: You cannot place the buttons side by side.

Comment: It's not customizable. There's nothing you can do.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Why is it not possible?Cant we do some styling?

Comment: @KshamaJain I don't know. No we can't.

Comment: Why - because Google said so, period. A homogeneous layout across notifications regarding such major components is way more important, than any individual developers vanities. Conformity is not a bad, but a good thing here. Taking this notification ecosystem back into the 90s, “look at my cool new WinAmp skin”-style, is not desirable.